# When using grails db-reverse-engineer, how do I specify that the generator should be "sequence" rather than "assigned"?

Tags: postgresql, grails

I'm using the grails db-reverse-engineer plugin to generate domain classes from an existing PostgreSQL database.

Each table in the database has an associated sequence that determines the next id. For example, the table "table" with the primary key column "t_id" uses the sequence "table_t_id_seq".

When I use db-reverse-engineer to generate domain classes, it generates a mapping as follows:

```
id column: "t_id", generator: "assigned"
```

This caused an error and after some searching and tinkering, I discovered that the appropriate mapping is as follows:

```
id column: "t_id", generator: "sequence", params: [sequence: "table_t_id_seq"]
```

Is there any way to configure db-reverse-engineer to generate the latter rather than the former? I'd rather not have to modify all the domain classes I generate to make them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that bit is hard-coded. You can create a feature request at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPREVERSEENGINEER